# How to disable Boot menu (F10-F12) on laptop?

Tags: boot

While turning on my laptop, I wanted to disable a possibility to use "F10" boot menu (maybe it's **F12** on other models). I want that no-one should be able to enter my DESKTOP (Even though I'm also using user-account password at Windows login screen). So, if BOOT is available, someone might use LIVE-CD to access my pc.

How to do that?

Comment: If you disable it, logic would dictate, you would never be able to enable it. A better idea would be to enable a password, so access to the boot menu, is simply prevented.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it in two days. Otherwise your question will keep getting bumped to the front page as a question with no accepted answer.

Comment: **I've found solution:**

1) set **POWER-ON PASSWORD** in BIOS, so, while laptop is TURNED ON, it immediately asks for password.
     ___________________________________                       2) + also, from **Windows Desktop>power options** properties, i put a **password after resuming to windows** from STANDBY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to do this is completely dependent on your BIOS's options.  You may or may not be able to disable to boot menu in BIOS.  Most BIOS's will let you password protect entry into BIOS so users cant change options.